# Network programming in swift?

Tags: ios, sockets, swift, network-programming

How do you create sockets in swift? I'm new to swift but I've heard that you can use Swift code alongside Objective C and C code. How accurate is this statement? In C I would do something like this so could I add this C code into a swift function?

```c
// get server ip from server name
if ((he = gethostbyname(host)) == NULL) {
die("gethoatbyname failed");
}
char *serverIP = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);

// create socket
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
die("socket failed");
}

// construct server address
memset(&hostAddr, 0, sizeof(hostAddr));
hostAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
hostAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIP);
hostAddr.sin_port = htons(mdbServPort);

// connect
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&hostAddr, sizeof(hostAddr)) < 0) {
die("connect failed);
}
FILE *Socket;
if ((Socket = fdopen(sock, "r")) == NULL) {
die("fdopen failed);
}
```

Or is there a preferred notation in swift? I haven't really been able to find much about it on Google. I would also appreciate being pointed toward some reading if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start to read about CFNetwork here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html

or you could use a third party library like this:
https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket
and read the code to see how ytcpsocket.c is implemented on top of BSD socket library.